# Form report WFFM Sitecore 8.0

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

I know that in WFFM 2.5 for Sitecore 7.5 we can see this following report:

- Summary
- Engagement analytics
- usability report
- save failure report

But they change the structure on WFFM 8.0 we can only just see the high-level report submissions.

What i want to ask are:

1. Is there any way to see dropout report and other report that available in WFFM 2.5 in WFFM 8.0
2. Is there any way to  to view data from forms that were not submitted successfully in WFFM 8?

Comment: The Save to Database Action was disabled in Sitecore 8.0 in favour of high level data. However I'm pretty sure you can enable it again and use a SQL db to save the responses - Here's a post showing you how to set that up - http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/web-forms-for-marketers-8-0-how-to-save-to-database

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately these reports are no longer available in the xDB versions of Sitecore (7.5+).

The data *is collected* however, you can see see the AJAX call in the network panel of your browser and you can the data in Mongo but no reports are available to view this data.

You only option at the moment would be to query Mongo yourself and create your own report.

I also suggest you raise a ticket with Sitecore Support asking for these reports to be added back into the module.